# simple drop down box

Tags: html, hover

I have a nav bar with 4 links. 3 are direct links and 1 should drop down to 3 more links.
I am struggling to get the ul.services to reappear when hovering over the services link.

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="services">services</a>
<ul id="drop_down">
<li><a href="#">Profit</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Profit</a></li>
<li><a href="#"">Profit</a></li>
</ul>
<a href="#">about</a>
<a href="#">contact</a>
<a href="#">testimonials</a>
```

CSS

```
#drop_down{
display: none;
position: absolute;
list-style-type: none;
text-align: right;
margin-left: 0;
padding-left: 0;
}
a:hover{
color: red;
}
.services:hover > #drop_down{
display: block;
}
```

Can anybody help.
Thanks

Comment: HTML is not correctly formatted. Tags are not proper.

Comment: Just a reminder that your touch device using visitors won't be experiencing your hover styles.

Comment: Edited, is this now proper.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do that is using `JQuery` with `.hover()` and `fadeIn(), .fadeOut()` functions, but first you need to know is that your html code have lot of errors.

HTML corrected:

```
<a href="#" class="services">services</a>
<ul id="drop_down">
    <li><a href="#">Profit</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Profit</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Profit</a></li>
</ul>
<a href="#">about</a>
<a href="#">contact</a>
<a href="#">testimonials</a>
```

JQuery code:

```
$("ul").css("display","none");

$(".services").hover(function(){
    $("ul").fadeIn();
},function(){
    $("ul").hover(function(){},function(){
        $("ul").fadeOut();
    });    
});
```

Just take a look to that [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/9xscg/)